# How to safely destroy an AC Adapter?

Tags: ac

I purchased an AC adapter for a nintendo wii. It hasn't worked and every fuse I put in to it appears to blow.

The seller has offered to refund me and send me a new one if I send him a photo of the destroyed AC adapter. He's suggested submerging it in water which I feel uncomfortable with for obvious reasons.

What is the safest way I can visibly destroy my AC adapter?

Comment: If you have a hammer every problem looks like a nail...

Comment: I don't own one unfortunately. I could smash it against a wall. lol this is probably not the sort of question normally posted here I just want to be 100% sure what I'm doing is safe.

Comment: Take a drill and make a large hole (like 10mm; more than one hole if you want) through the adapter.  You can stick a pencil through the hole to make it more apparent on the photo.

Comment: Do you have a car? Or you could take it down to your nearest fire station and ask the boys there to lend you a hand. They've got some great tools.

Comment: If you don't have a hammer and need one a lot of readily available objects can function like a hammer quite easily, like stones and bricks. In most cases we have to convince people not to use inappropriate tools, but in this cease nearly every tool is appropriate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut the cord off **right where it comes out of the box** with some sturdy kitchen shears. Take a photo- that will probably be good enough. That method was used for 'destruction' of non-compliant adapters that were considered unsafe.

I can think of other ways of destroying an AC adapter, but the seller might not readily recognize the remains. For example, .45ACP slug, ceramic kiln, various machine tools etc.

Comment: Thanks
https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t35.0-12/11297128_10206586697284009_116368215_o.jpg?oh=d979c19fed7d2a9e6103e7af4b2cb982&oe=55772C94

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to safely destroy electronic devices.  Some of those include:

Smashing with hammer or sledge hammer.

Cutting in pieces with a band saw or hacksaw.

Submerging a sealed device as your seller suggests is NOT a very good way of destroying your AC adapter.

There are more fun ways of doing this but all involve some hazards.  You could burn it up with a blow torch or do as Steve Ciarcia (of Circuit Cellar Ink fame) did with some of his old hard drives: take it out to a target range and blow holes in it with a gun.

And, of course, you could use a Blendtec blender to "See if it blends".  Search YouTube for "Blendtec" or "Will It Blend" if you don't know what I'm talking about.

I'm kinda partial to applying large amounts of electrical energy to said devices (it's amazing what you can do with a 480 Vac 100 Amp distro) but that is actively frowned upon where I come from.

Comment: Would scissors be safe to cut the wire? I know I should make the most of this and smash the shit out of it, torch it etc but I'm a bit short on tools so I'm going to be boring.

Comment: Scissors to the wire may not satisfy the seller; wires can easily be repaired in several ways.

Comment: As long as it's safe I'd like to do it then go on to the more dangerous transformer stuff if he doesn't accept cut wires. Will I get fried if I cut the wire whilst it's unplugged?

Answer (score 0):

The most expensive part of an AC adapter is usually the transformer. In addition, many use a custom transformer that can only be ordered with a minimum run in the thousands or tens of thousands. If you open up the adapter and tear apart the windings of the main transformer then it will render the adapter inoperable and not easily/cheaply repairable.

Don't forget to discharge all the capacitors first though, in order to prevent injury or death.

Comment: How do I discharge them? Capacitors are the reason I'm asking this question. I don't think I need to be too thorough when convincing him but preventing death or injury is pretty high on my priorities as I know nothing about electronics.

Comment: Put a screwdriver across the terminals of each capacitor and hold for a few seconds. Repeat until it stops sparking, then do it one more time. Don't be holding onto the metal while doing this.